# Creating a folder RW in a ReadOnly FIle System on Slackware

Tags: linux, slackware

I have mounted the complete partition sda2 as read-only by playing around the start scripts. It has made the complete system RO except /dev folder. I wonder Why..?

Also, i want only one folder like /mnt/var/log to be RW and left all the folders as RO but even after trying to mount in multiple ways its not happening and its also RO.

Any way this thing can be achieved in Slackware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev` isn't a real filesystem; it is an interface to kernel-provided functionality which is exposed as though it were a filesystem because that makes it easy for all manner of programs to use. That's why it is writable despite your `/dev/sda2` mount being readonly. (You'll find `/proc` and, if you have it, `/sys` have similar behavior; the reason is the same.)

There is no way to specify a writable subset of a partition mounted readonly. If you want `/mnt/var/log` or what-have-you to behave in the same way `/dev` does, you'll need to do it the same way the kernel does for `/dev`: create a separate partition, and mount it read-write on the directory you want to be writable.

Answer (score 0):

To /dev is normally mounted a ramfs or a tmpfs, on which the software named udev creates/removes the devices based on its config and the messages of the kernel.

If you want a rw directory on a readonly root partition, a simple command is

```
mount ramfs /here/i/want/write -t ramfs
```

Comment: i don't think its a correct way. Its just directing the ramfs to the folder which will become RW but it will clear the data there and make it RW temporarily. Also, i don't think its a feasible option. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you have right. I give a better solution.

Comment: If you want make a readonly directory writable, you need to save somewhere your changes. This means a practical "unification" between a  readonly  directory and  a ramfs (or tmpfs, or any  other  writable  directory). This a relatively complex thing, but  very useful,  for   example,    linux livecd-s  are   working on the same  way.  Some  solution you can find for  these:  1)  unionfs (unionfs.org) 2)  aufs (aufs.sf.net)   3)   boot   an ubuntu  livecd   and check with  what it does  (I  forgot, but it is  the best,   for example it can  store the  changes on  a  permanent disk file)